# Extract first floating point number from right in excel string

Tags: regex, excel, string

I have an excel column full of strings, from which I am trying to extract one number.

Here is an example of a particular row (all rows follow this format):

`5) something here 93   4. something else- here too(24+Mths)    Y   Y   249 5) 24+ Months   1) lots more rubbish text   Y   N   some more rubbish text  24/04/2012  25/04/1999      0.263   10  L   rubbish text 3521.37233 4130    rubbish text1041023`.

I just need to extract the first decimal number from the right, in this case **3521.37233**.

UPDATE: I tried using Text to Columns with space as a delimiter, but there are varying number of spaces between characters. Is there a way to delimit by any number of spaces?

Comment: Have you tried using Text to Columns under the Data portion of the Ribbon? If you use a SPACE as the delimiter you might (depending on the consistency of your  data format) get a couple of columns you can keep and discard the rest.

Comment: @ExcelHero Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried it and it partially worked but unfortunately I was mistaken in thinking that the data was consistent :(. There are varying amounts of spaces. Is there a way to delimit by spaces regardless of the number of spaces?

Comment: In that case a simple workaround would be to make a new temporary column and use the Trim() function on the data in the original column. Trim() removes spaces before and after the entire text value... but it also removes duplicate spaces in-between words, leaving just ONE space between words. So, let's say your data are in column A and start in the first row. In cell `B1` enter this formula: `=Trim(A1)`  Now copy that formula all the way down. Now copy the entire column B and paste it back as values only. Now do the Text to Columns using column B as the source.

Comment: @ExcelHero Hi, I managed to simplify my problem a bit by extracting the second element I needed through LEFT(string, 11) to get the 11 digit number.  Now I just need that decimal number  (the first one from the right). I've updated the question to reflect :)

Comment: Did my simple workaround work? It should work for either your original goal of getting the two values... or for your revised question. But if it works for both, you won't need to do the RIGHT(string, 11) bit.

Comment: @ExcelHero I think it failed because the spaces were actually Tabs. Delimiting by tabs did the trick. If you  want to post your suggestion of using Text to Columns as an answer, please do so and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that can be done swiftly by Regex. Unfortunately, Excel does not support Regex using Excel formula.

You can use the following UDF (add this to your workbook).

Usage:

- if you want the last decimal number(i.e. 1st from the right): `=StrRegex([cell reference],"[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}",-1)`
- if you want all decimal numbers: `=StrRegex([cell reference],"[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}",0)`

```
Function StrRegex(findIn As String, pattern As String, Optional matchID As Long = 1, Optional separator As String = ",", Optional ignoreCase As Boolean = False) As String  ' matchID - 1-based, matchID=0 => return all

    Application.Volatile (True)

    Dim result As String
    Dim allMatches As Object
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Dim mc As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    re.pattern = pattern
    re.Global = True
    re.ignoreCase = ignoreCase
    Set allMatches = re.Execute(findIn)

    mc = allMatches.count
    If mc > 0 Then
        If matchID > mc Then
            result = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Else
            If matchID > 0 Then
                result = allMatches.Item(matchID - 1).Value
            ElseIf matchID < 0 Then
                result = allMatches.Item(mc + matchID).Value
            Else
                result = ""
                For i = 0 To allMatches.count - 1
                    result = result & separator & allMatches.Item(i).Value
                    For j = 0 To allMatches.Item(i).submatches.count - 1
                        result = result & separator & allMatches.Item(i).submatches.Item(j)
                    Next
                Next

                If Len(result) <> 0 Then
                    result = Right(result, Len(result) - Len(separator))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Else
        result = ""
    End If

    StrRegex = result

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

For any interested in a native Excel function solution, if you have the `FILTERXML` function, you can use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[number(.) = number(.) and contains(.,'.')][last()]")
```

The `xPath` looks for all nodes that are numeric, and also contain a `dot`, and then returns the last node that meets those specifications.

***Note:*** If your Windows regional settings are using the `dot` as a thousands separator, this will not work as written. You would have to replace the `.` with your system decimal separator.